# My BubbleSort alghorithm doesn't seem to work and I don't know why

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

I'm trying to sort the specified column of the matrix in descending order , but my sorting algorithm doesn't seem to work and  I don't know why.

```
void Prohod(float MAT[][4], int numberOfRows, int givenColumn) {
    float temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
        if (MAT[i][givenColumn] < MAT[i + 1][givenColumn]) {
            temp = MAT[i][givenColumn];
            MAT[i][givenColumn] = MAT[i + 1][givenColumn];
            MAT[i + 1][givenColumn] = temp;


        }
    }
    printf("Given column:%d\n",givenColumn);

}
```

I tried to apply the BubbleSort algorithm to batch the values , but for some reason it doesn't work.

Comment: One issue: the upper bound of your `for` loop appears to be too large by one.  If the value passed as `numberOfRows` is to be taken as the first dimension of the matrix, then the valid index values for that dimension are `0` through `numberOfRows-1`.  In that case, when `i` takes the value `numberOfRows-1`, the expression `MAT[i + 1][givenColumn]` will attempt to an out-of-bounds access.

Comment: Another issue: your function performs only one pass of Bubble Sort.  A Proper Bubble Sort repeats an equivalent of that `for` loop until it performs a pass in which no swaps are performed.

Comment: Possible third issue: you are sorting only the values of one column, but it seems more likely that you want to sort whole rows by the values of that column.

Comment: Could you simplify what is then wrong I don't think I understand , and yes I am trying to sort only one column.

Comment: Your `for` loop does _one_ full _pass_ at the [column] array. So, at the end, the _last_ element will be guaranteed to be in sort (i.e. largest), but none of the others will. You have to have an outer `for` loop that repeats this N times. Or, until the [now] inner loop shows _no_ swap.

Comment: Yes thank you , I have fixed it before you answered , I have added the loop as you are  writing right now. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I added another for loop for the following element like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
     for (int j = i + 1; j < numberOfRows; j++) {
                     if (MAT[i][givenColumn] < MAT[j][givenColumn]) {
                        temp = MAT[i][givenColumn];
                        MAT[i][givenColumn] = MAT[j][givenColumn];
                        MAT[j][givenColumn] = temp;
                     }
               }

}
```

And It works now.

Comment: I don't think this is a bubble sort anymore. Bubble sort always compares consecutive elements.

Comment: Then what it is  , it works for me now with this .

Comment: I didn't say it didn't work, just that it's not a bubble sort. It's similar to a _selection_ sort. But, a selection sort does N compares and _one_ swap per pass: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort

Answer (score 1):

1. You are going one element too far with `MAT[i + 1]` in your `for` loop
2. Your `for` loop does *one* full *pass* at the [column] array.
3. So, at the end, the *last* element will be guaranteed to be in sort (i.e. largest).
4. But, none of the others will.
5. You have to have an outer `for` loop that repeats this N times (e.g. a "pass" counter).
6. Or, until the [now] inner loop shows *no* swap.
7. On each subsequent pass, the last element of the previous pass is guaranteed to be in the correct place, so we can decrease the number of elements we check by one

Here is the improved code:

```
void
Prohod(float MAT[][4], int numberOfRows, int givenColumn)
{
    float temp;

    for (int pass = 0; i < numberOfRows; pass++) {
        int swap = 0;

        // after a single pass, the _last_ element is guaranteed to be correct
        // so we can look at one fewer element on each pass
        int curcount = (numberOfRows - 1) - pass;

        for (int i = 0; i < curcount; i++) {
            if (MAT[i][givenColumn] < MAT[i + 1][givenColumn]) {
                temp = MAT[i][givenColumn];
                MAT[i][givenColumn] = MAT[i + 1][givenColumn];
                MAT[i + 1][givenColumn] = temp;
                swap = 1;
            }
        }

        // early escape -- no swaps occurred -- all are in sort
        if (! swap)
            break;
    }

    printf("Given column:%d\n", givenColumn);
}
```